# How to modify a plot when ggpredict is used - Title, Spacing, Line coloring/dashes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am a novice R programmer, and I am using ggpredict in R to create plots from my lmer model. My model and my first plot are as follows:

```
modelprop <- lmer(GROWTH ~ TREATMENT*NFIXING*Total_in_QUAD_scaled*proportion_fixers_scaled +
                    TREATMENT*NFIXING*days_since_hurricane_scaled +
                    HEIGHTi_scaled*NFIXING +
                    (1 | PLOT/unique_ID) + (1 | SPECIES),
                  data = data_allscaled_droughtless)

predictions <- ggpredict(modelprop, terms = c("TREATMENT", "NFIXING"))
plot(predictions)
```

The resulting plot looks like:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFPnQ.png)

I would like to reduce the amount of space between control and warming (treatments on x-axis), eliminate the title, change the axes titles, and eliminate the legend on the right.

Additionally I would like to make changes to my second plot:

```
predictions2 <- ggpredict(modelprop, terms = c("proportion_fixers_scaled", "Total_in_QUAD_scaled", "NFIXING", "TREATMENT"))
plot(predictions2)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khhvo.png)

I would like to eliminate the title, change the axes titles, and eliminate the legend on the right. I would also like to make some of the lines (in my case, the non-significant lines) so that they are dashed or otherwise indicate non-significance. If this is not possible, I would prefer to eliminate them completely.

I have tried to use the ggeffects package to no success. I have also read that the ggggeffects package may be useful, but I am having a hard time discerning the syntax of this package. I appreciate any guidance or any attempts to point me to any relevant tutorials or texts. Thank you.

Comment: If you need more little, detailed modifications for your plot, you most likely need to additionally use the ggplot2-package. Here are some examples, which do not directly address your problem, but may give an impression of how to do it: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotcustomize.html